# Buttons not appearing in custom ribbon group

Tags: ribbon

I'm trying to add a new group to the list form display ribbon that contains a few buttons. The group is created but it's blank. Here's the Elements.xml that defines the CustomAction:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction Id="BilSimser.Ribbon.CustomerGroup" 
                Location="CommandUI.Ribbon" RegistrationId="100" RegistrationType="List">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Groups._children">
          <Group Id="BilSimser.Ribbon.ListForm.Display.CustomerGroup"
                 Sequence="100" Title="Customers"
                 Description="Links to customer views"
                 Template="Ribbon.Templates.Flexible">
            <Controls Id="BilSimser.Ribbon.ListForm.Display.CustomerGroup.Controls">
              <Button Id="BilSimser.Ribbon.ListForm.Display.CustomerGroup.OutageCustomerButton"
                      Sequence="10"
                      Command="BilSimser.CustomerGroup.Command.OutageCustomers"
                      TemplateAlias="o1"
                      Image16by16="/_layouts/images/FOLDER16.GIF"
                      Image32by32="/_layouts/images/FOLDER32.GIF"
                      LabelText="Outage Customers"/>
              <Button Id="BilSimser.Ribbon.ListForm.Display.CustomerGroup.CustomerClassificationButton"
                      Sequence="20"
                      Command="BilSimser.CustomerGroup.Command.CustomerClassification"
                      TemplateAlias="o1"
                      Image16by16="/_layouts/images/FOLDER16.GIF"
                      Image32by32="/_layouts/images/FOLDER32.GIF"
                      LabelText="Customer Classification"/>
              <Button Id="BilSimser.Ribbon.ListForm.Display.CustomerGroup.CriticalCustomerButton"
                      Sequence="30"
                      Command="BilSimser.CustomerGroup.Command.CriticalCustomers"
                      TemplateAlias="o1"
                      Image16by16="/_layouts/images/FOLDER16.GIF"
                      Image32by32="/_layouts/images/FOLDER32.GIF"
                      LabelText="Critical Customers"/>
              <Button Id="BilSimser.Ribbon.ListForm.Display.CustomerGroup.MajorCustomerButton"
                      Sequence="40"
                      Command="BilSimser.CustomerGroup.Command.MajorCustomers"
                      TemplateAlias="o1"
                      Image16by16="/_layouts/images/FOLDER16.GIF"
                      Image32by32="/_layouts/images/FOLDER32.GIF"
                      LabelText="Major Customers"/>
              <Button Id="BilSimser.Ribbon.ListForm.Display.CustomerGroup.StandardCustomerButton"
                      Sequence="50"
                      Command="BilSimser.CustomerGroup.Command.StandardCustomers"
                      TemplateAlias="o1"
                      Image16by16="/_layouts/images/FOLDER16.GIF"
                      Image32by32="/_layouts/images/FOLDER32.GIF"
                      LabelText="Standard Customers"/>
            </Controls>
          </Group>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler Command="BilSimser.CustomerGroup.Command.OutageCustomers"
                          CommandAction="javascript:SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('outage customers');"/>
        <CommandUIHandler Command="BilSimser.CustomerGroup.Command.CustomerClassification"
                          CommandAction="javascript:SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('customer classification');"/>
        <CommandUIHandler Command="BilSimser.CustomerGroup.Command.CriticalCustomers"
                          CommandAction="javascript:SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('critical customers');"/>
        <CommandUIHandler Command="BilSimser.CustomerGroup.Command.MajorCustomers"
                          CommandAction="javascript:SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('major customers');"/>
        <CommandUIHandler Command="BilSimser.CustomerGroup.Command.StandardCustomers"
                          CommandAction="javascript:SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('standard customers');"/>
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Comment: I've tried the above example from Bil with the changes from Andrey and it is telling me that the schema is invalid when I add the Scaling element. It looks like that element can only be under a Tab element... so how did you add it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bil! Looks like, you have missed Scaling element inside Groups element.
Try add this to your definition:

```
      <Scaling Id="BilSimser.Ribbon.ListForm.Display.CustomerGroup.Scaling">
        <MaxSize
          Id="BilSimser.Ribbon.ListForm.Display.CustomerGroup.MaxSize"
          GroupId="BilSimser.Ribbon.ListForm.Display.CustomerGroup"
          Size="Large" />
        <Scale
          Id="BilSimser.Ribbon.ListForm.Display.CustomerGroup.Scale"
          GroupId="BilSimser.Ribbon.ListForm.Display.CustomerGroup"
          Size="Large" />
      </Scaling>

      <!-- Group element goes here -->
```

Also, as Andy Burns mentioned, it is better to always recreate Group Templates (you can "steal" their definitions from end of the "14\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL\XML\CMDUI.XML" file :)

The Ribbon.ListForm.Display tab uses only Flexible2 template, so this might be the reason too. To recreate Ribbon.Templates.Flexible, you can add this code to your definition:

```
<CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Templates._children">
  <GroupTemplate Id="BilSimser.Ribbon.Templates.Flexible">
    <Layout Title="Large">
      <OverflowSection Type="OneRow" TemplateAlias="o1" DisplayMode="Large"/>
    </Layout>
    <Layout Title="Medium">
      <OverflowSection Type="ThreeRow" TemplateAlias="o1" DisplayMode="Medium"/>
    </Layout>
    <Layout Title="MediumTwoRow">
      <OverflowSection Type="TwoRow" TemplateAlias="o1" DisplayMode="Medium" />
    </Layout>
    <Layout Title="Small">
      <OverflowSection Type="ThreeRow" TemplateAlias="o1" DisplayMode="Small" />
    </Layout>
    <Layout Title="Popup" LayoutTitle="Large" />
  </GroupTemplate>
 </CommandUIDefinition>
```

Also, do not forget to fix reference to template in this line:

```
       Template="BilSimser.Ribbon.Templates.Flexible">
```

Hope this helps! (sorry, cannot test myself to garantee 100% result, got SharePoint down on my computer after installing last CU :(... )

Comment: Thanks omlin, I had to add both the scaling and a custom group template to get it to work.

Answer (score 5):

You may well need to define your own GroupTemplate. The out of box ones - such as Ribbon.Template.Flexible - are not *necessarily* available.

http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2010/10/10/always-create-your-own-group-templates-with-sharepoint-ribbon-customizations.aspx

Comment: +1: yes that is what i have found as well http://spc3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/59904#1012111